# Nonstandard options in jvm.xml

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, java

In the jvm.xml file there are already some settings given as an example.

```
<Option Name="-Xmx" Value="50m"/>
<Option Name="-Xms" Value="20m"/>
<Option Name="-Dfile.encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
```

It is possible to add other JVM options to Tridion jvm.xml file, like -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio, and how, i.e. will the JVM initialization methods actually take them into account?

If the answer is yes, does it actually help decreasing the size of the spawned JVM?

Comment: Have you already tried adding something like `<Option Name="-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio" Value="60"/>`?

Comment: Thank you, Bart! Yes, I have tried that, but I am not sure it is actually getting picked up by JVM initialization. What I get in the Event Viewer is this: Setting the following JVM -XX startup option key/value: 'X:MaxHeapFreeRatio' / '60'. Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: That sure sounds to me like it works